# Can ifelse be used effectively with outputs that have no return?

Tags: r, if-statement, vectorization

Consider the following example code:

```
b<-0
plot(0,0)
ranVec<-runif(100)
f1<-function()#ran 40% of the time
  {
    b<-b+1
    points(b,4)
  }
f2<-function()#ran 60% of the time
  {
    b<-b-1
    points(b,4)
  }
```

I'm currently dealing with something very similar and my next line of code is effectively:

```
for(i in 1:100)
{
   if(ranVec[i]<=0.4) f1
   else f2
}
```

But would it have been possible to achieve this previous block's outcome with `ifelse`? For example, what I really wanted to write was:

```
ifelse(rawResults<=0.4, f1, f2)
```

But this throws an error presumably concerning the length of the output.

Comment: @akrun In the real example, the code in question was called inside of a function. Come to think of it, that means that this code printed here doesn't need ```return```.

Comment: `ifelse` is intended to deal with *data*, not functions. (Even at that, it is known to drop class from some types of data.) You might do `ifelse(rawResults <= 0.4, f1(rawResults), f2(rawResults))`, which will call the functions with all data, and intersperse the results based on the condition. For instance, try `vec <- 1:10; ifelse(vec %% 2 == 0, vec - 1, vec + 100)`, which calculates `vec - 1` and `vec + 100` for all values in `vec`, but intersperses the decreased or increased values based on the condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To @r2evans point, `ifelse` is for data. For functions you can use something like `walk`

```
purrr::walk(ranVec, ~if(.x <= 0.4) f1() else f2())
```

Not sure what your actual application is, but if you can, it will be faster if you calculate all the points (particularly if you can vectorize the calculation) and then add them to the plot all at once instead of one by one.